# Errors installing XWiiMote

Tags: raspbian

I am having trouble compiling/installing XWiiMote.
When i run either **configure** or **autogen.sh**, it complains about not finding ncurses:

```
~/xwiimote $ sudo ./autogen.sh
...
checking for NCURSES... no
configure: error: Package requirements (ncurses) were not met:
No package 'ncurses' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you 
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables NCURSES_CFLAGS 
and NCURSES_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.

~/xwiimote $ dpkg -l |grep ncurses
libncurses5:armhf  5.9-10
libncursesw5:armhf 5.9-10
ncurses-base       5.9-10
ncurses-bin        5.9-10
ncurses-term       5.9-10

~/xwiimote $
```

I don't know enough about Linux to understand the recommendations about environment variables...
What do i need to do?

Thanks!

[my OS deets:

```
Raspberry Pi Model B rev 2
Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy) 
3.18.7+ #755 PREEMPT
```

]

Comment: The error is because it can';t find ncurses; give this a try: sudo apt-get install ncurses-base ncurses-bin install

Comment: Yes, i've already figured out that much by reading the error message... As you can see at the end of my question text, ncurses-base and ncurses-bin are already installed and up to date. What i'm trying to find out is how to deal with the error as per the suggestions regarding environment variables.

Answer (score 2):

According to the very readable and understandable explanation by Alan De Smet at
https://askubuntu.com/questions/210210/pkg-config-path-environment-variable, this error occurs when pkg-config can't find a `.pc` file for the indicated dependency package.
(Thanks Alan!)

After searching my system for some kind of ncurses.pc file, none was found.
So, as per Alan's suggestion, i installed `libncurses5-dev` in order to have an ncurses.pc file.

The package xwiimote now configures and builds just fine. :-)

Comment: This is how most library packages are organized; they have parts which only serve a purpose when compiled against, and so those parts are kept in a seperate `-dev` (for "development") package.  If you are ever compiling something and it complains it needs libfoobar, you need to search for/install `foobar-dev`.

Comment: Ah. I did not know that. Now I do. Thanks goldilocks. :-)